# Filed taxes for 2016, 2017, then 2018. Now got the confirmation for 2018, is that order fishy?

Tags: taxes, germany

I helped somebody else file their German taxes. We could go back until tax year 2016 and I know that you have to file them in chronological order. Therefore we sent off 2016, then 2017 and after that 2018. A few days ago they got an email stating that their filing for 2018 was accepted.

This makes me a bit uneasy because on the tax form it asks whether one has a tax ID number from previous filings. When we sent away 2017 and 2018 it is true that they did not have such a number from previous filings, and they did not hear from the tax office until then. But technically tax for previous years was at least *sent* to the tax office.

One has 30 days to appeal to it. Do I have to do something or will the other years just come back in random order?

Comment: Do the German tax authority have a phone line where you could ask this question? In the UK they are very helpful with this type of thing.

Comment: They also have a form on their website, question is submitted there.

Comment: "return statement" in your title is quite confusing.  It seems you mean you have confirmation that the taxing authority accepted the tax return?  That could be called a "confirmation", "acceptance confirmation", or similar.  Just "got the statement" gives no hint as to what is being stated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They have replied via email, saying that they are working on the other tax years as well. So it seems that this is not an indicator of anything going wrong.